# Text file from another site

Tags: php, html

I have a a text file called sideup.txt it sits on http://site2.com/sideup.txt (in html format)
I would like to take this text file and use it in my http://mow.org.il/
how will I be able to do that ?

I am using the pivotx engine with the magazine template the idea is to put on 1 site links that are taken from site2

thanks
Shoshana

Answer (score 3):

In the site2's PHP

```
echo file_get_contents('http://site1.com/sideup.txt');
```

Comment: the question is tagged 'HTML' why assume they even have php setup?

Comment: Because it is impossible to do it with pure HTML. Others post answers also with PHP/JS however it is still tagged with `html`.

Comment: actually, using an iframe would allow serving remote content, though it may look pretty crap. JS is supported by browsers, assuming a server side technology is in use is rarely wise.

Comment: I have tryed all variations but am unable to do it

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be to use PHP and use `<?php echo file_get_contents("sideup.txt"); ?>` in place where you want the content of the `sideup.txt` file to appear.

Comment: the question is tagged 'HTML' why assume they even have php setup?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state how you want to achieve this, what languages/frameworks you can use. Using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://site1.com/sideup.txt",
    dataType: 'html',
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
      $("#yourTargetTagHere").empty;
      $("#yourTargetTagHere").html(data);
  }
});
```

In the code above replace yourTargetTagHere with the ID of the tag you wish to replace, e.g.

```
<!-- page content div -->
<div id='PageContentDiv></div>
```

I chose a jQuery solution because the question is tagged as HTML, rather than assuming that they can run PHP.

Comment: It would help if you specified what you have to work with when asking a question. Regardless, the jQuery ajax method works.